# Existe alguma regra de palavra chave no Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Como funcionam as palavras chave no Google Play?

Existe alguma forma de inserir palavras chave? Ou ele utiliza a descrição do App?

Comment: Como assim `Como funcionam as palavras chave no Google Play?` ? Você quer saber como o Google sabe o tipo ( saude, esportes, games, produtividade) do seu app ou quer saber qual o criterio utilizado para que seu app apareça no topo das buscas do Google Play?

Comment: O critério utilizado para q seu APP apareça nas buscas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer com que o seu aplicativo apareça no topo das pesquisas do Google Play, você deve tirar proveito do algoritmo de busca e rankeamento do Google Play - pois é ele quem irá determinar o quão no topo o seu aplicativo deve aparecer - e  seguir algumas boas práticas de publicação para tornar o seu aplicativo mais atrativo para download , independente da posição dele.

Aqui vão algumas dicas para tirar proveito desses dois mecanismos:

**Algoritmo de busca e rankeamento Google Play**:

- Colocar a sua principal palavra-chave no título do aplicativo: Isso poderia melhorar drasticamente a sua posição ( de 80 a 100 pontos). Há também uma recomendação para colocar o nome do aplicativo no ícone do aplicativo e usar o nome do aplicativo para sua palavra-chave, mas acho que não é uma boa ideia ter palavras em um ícone.
- Usar até 5 vezes as palavras-chave da sua aplicação na descrição do mesmo. No Google Play Store as palavras chave são pesquisáveis, portanto, certifique-se de repeti-las com uma boa frequência ( mas não mais que 5x, pois isso não fará diferença e sobrecarregará a descrição do app).
- Obter bons comentários
- Possuir boa frequência de utilização do aplicativo
- Possuir um grande número de avaliações
- Possuir uma boa quantidade de downloads do app
- Possuir um bom crescimento de downloads ( aumento dos downloads ao longo dos últimos 30 dias)
- Possuir poucas desinstalações ( quantidade de pessoas desinstalaram o seu app)
- Possuir boa frequencia de uso
- Fazer com que as pessoas comentem sobre o seu aplicativo em outros lugares

**Boas práticas de publicação:**

- Ter um design bonito e screenshots para mostrar aos potenciais usuários do seu app o que ele é capaz de fazer.
- Ter um vídeo de demonstração / promo.
- Ter uma descrição simples e objetiva, focando em suas principais funcionalidades e no diferencial do seu aplicativo em realação aos outros.

**Conteúdo inteiramente retirado de:** http://www.apptamin.com/blog/optimize-play-store-app/